# difference between Set<Class<PupilVO>> and Set<PupilVO>

Tags: java, android

I need to find the difference between the following:

```
Set<PupilVO> hold = new TreeSet<PupilVO>();
```

and

```
Set<Class<PupilVO>> hold = new TreeSet<Class<PupilVO>>();//class object
```

is there any added advantage with this class object stuff ?
what exactly can you do with class objects, or in other words.. what purpose does it serve?

Comment: Read the javadoc of the classes you use. Then look up _reflection_.

Comment: Do you understand the difference between a `Class<PupilVO>` and `PupilVO`?

Comment: Well, in one case you have `PupilVO` elements, in the other you have `Class` elements... Those are not the same at all

Comment: no i don't understand the difference

Answer (score 1):

There's a big difference.  The first holds a bunch of pupil objects.  The second holds a bunch of pupil object class definitions.  The second is useful for reflection, especially if you're holding multiple types of classes.  But if you need to know anything normally inside a pupil getting at it is slow and difficult via the second method.  Its fast and easy via the first.

Comment: if i understand you correctly, class definitions are for getting information about a particular class is that right ?

Comment: Yes, for use in reflection.